# Having trouble when allocating memory when passing a double pointers address into a triple pointer

Tags: c

I'm creating a double pointer and sending in the address to allocate memory, which requires a triple pointer. Also, i am creating single pointers (goals and assists) and sending their addresses to allocate memory, which requires double pointers. I think the problem lies in allocation of memory, but i cant figure it out. I keep seg faulting whenever i run the readLinesFromFile function. It does not segfault when I try running allocateMemory function by itself. The problem could also be in the readLinesFromFile function

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int numPlayers = 0;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Missing text file");
        return 0;
    }
    char **playerNames;
    int *goals, *assists;


        FILE *filePtr = fopen(argv[1],"r");

         if(filePtr == NULL)
         {
             printf("\nFile is empty");
             return 0;
         }
  numPlayers = countLinesInFile(filePtr);

  allocateMemory(&goals,&assists,&playerNames,numPlayers);

  readLinesFromFile(filePtr,goals,assists,playerNames,numPlayers);


}


void allocateMemory(int **goals, int **assists, char *** names, int size)
{

    int i = 0;

    *goals = malloc(MAX_NAME * sizeof(int));

    *assists = malloc(MAX_NAME * sizeof(int));

    *names = malloc(MAX_NAME * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        (names[i]) = malloc(MAX_NAME * sizeof(char*));
    }
}
void readLinesFromFile(FILE *fptr, int *goals, int *assists, char **names, int numLines)
{

    int i = 0, j = 0, x = 0;

    char players[MAX_LINE];

    char *tokenPtr;

   fptr = fopen(INPUT,"r");

   for(i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
   {
       fgets(players,MAX_LINE, fptr);

       tokenPtr = strtok(players," ");
       strcpy((*(names+i)), tokenPtr);

       while (tokenPtr != NULL)
       {
           tokenPtr = strtok(NULL," ");
           if (x = 0)
           {
               goals[i] = atoi(tokenPtr);
               x = 1;
           }
           else
           {
               assists[i] = atoi(tokenPtr);
               x = 0;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `(*(*(names+i) = malloc(size * sizeof(char))));` has some misplaced paranthesis. Try `*(*(names+i)) = malloc(size * sizeof(char));`

Comment: i see what you mean and i changed it, but it still segfaults :(

Comment: Just to be sure, you want goals and assists to be a single dimensioned array and names to be a psuedo 2-dimension array?

Comment: Well the way you do it you limit the name length to the number of lines in your file - same size value... Not sure that's intentional.

Comment: Well, i have to use the functions how they are. with allocate memory asking for **goals, **assists,***names, size
and readlinesfromfilesasking for *goals, *assists, **names, size

when i declare just *names in main and try to send the address into allocate memory. I get an error that im sending in the wrong type.

i am new to programming

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but consider this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: @icepack: To initialise a pointer array down in a function I see no other way but using three stars.

Comment: @alk it's a question of design. The real question to be asked here is: "*is it really the best approach to the problem to solve*"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MAX_NAME` is the maximum length of a player's name, this should work:

```
void AllocateMemory(char *** pppNames, int ** ppGoals, int ** ppAssists, size_t sizePlayersMax)
{
  *pppNames = malloc(sizePlayersMax * sizeof **pppNames);
  *ppGoals  = malloc(sizePlayersMax * sizeof **ppGoals);9
  *ppAssists = malloc(sizePlayersMax * sizeof **ppAssists);

  {
    size_t sizePlayersCount = 0;0
    for (; sizePlayersCount < sizePlayersMax; ++sizePlayersCount)
    {
      (*pppNames)[sizePlayersCount] = calloc(MAX_NAME + 1, sizeof *((*pppNames)[sizePlayersCount]));
    }
  }
}
```

To prevent the app from overwriting memory in case of really long player names you might like to change this line:

```
strcpy((*(names+i)), tokenPtr);
```

to become:

```
if (tokenPtr) 
  strncpy((*(names+i)), tokenPtr, MAX_NAME);
```

This would truncate the player names stored to a maximum of `MAX_NAME` characters. The latter is the size `AllocateMemory()` use minus `1`. This one spare character is needed for the `0`/`NUL` to terminate the character-array so it could be used as a "string".

Finally also this is dangerous:

```
while (tokenPtr != NULL)
{
  tokenPtr = strtok(NULL," ");

  if (x = 0)
  {
```

Better do like this:

```
while (NULL != (tokenPtr = strtok(NULL," ")))
{
  if (x = 0)
  {
```